# C# thread-safe atomic operation on item in ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: c#, concurrency, thread-safety, atomic

How do I perform an atomic operation on an item whose key may or may not be in a ConcurrentDictionary as yet?

For example, say I want to reset some state values on an item with a specific key, and it may or may not be in the dictionary as yet. I don't want to reset all state values, so simply replacing the original item with a new instance is not an option.

Here's a contrived example which is quite similar to my use case. You can assume the classes & methods contain more code which does not influence the problem at hand.

```
public class MyManager
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<int, MyWorker> _dict
        = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, MyWorker>();

    public void DoSomething1()
    {
        // ...
        _dict.GetOrAdd(1, new MyWorker(Guid.NewGuid()));
        // ...
    }

    public void DoSomething2()
    {
        // ...
        _dict.TryRemove(1, out MyWorker worker);
        // ...
    }

    public void DoSomething3()
    {
        // OPTION 1: Won't it be possible for a different thread to remove
        // the object before the Reset() call?
        var myWorker = _dict.GetOrAdd(1, new MyWorker(Guid.NewGuid()));
        myWorker.Reset();
        // OPTION 2: Does method chaining somehow guarantee execution within
        // the same lock?
        _dict.GetOrAdd(1, new MyWorker(Guid.NewGuid())).Reset();
        // OPTION 3: ?
    }
}

public class MyWorker
{
    private int _someValue = 1;
    private IList<string> _someList = new List<string>();
    private Guid _immutableValue; // should not get reset

    public MyWorker(Guid immutableValue)
    {
        _immutableValue = immutableValue;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        _someValue = 1;
        _someList = new List<string>();
        // NB. do not change _immutableValue!
    }
}
```

In this example, different threads might call DoSomething1() or DoSomething2() multiple times in any order, which could lead to the MyWorker with key "1" being replaced in the dictionary at any time.

I need DoSomething3() to call MyWorker.Reset() and know that if the object already exists in the dictionary, that object will be used.

1. Option 1 allows the retrieved MyWorker to be replaced with a new instance before I have called Reset.
2. Option 2 seems like it would do the same thing, unless there is special handling when used fluently?

What other options exist to retrieve a value and execute a method/operation on it within the same lock that retrieved it before the lock is released? In other words, how to guarantee an atomic operation? Can I pass in a lambda somehow?

Comment: It sounds like it could be an interesting question, but I'm lost to what you'e actually asking. Can you please explain what problem you're solving and what's going wrong?

Comment: Have you checked out `AddOrUpdate`?

Comment: @yaakov `AddOrUpdate` doesn't appear to have an overload which allows a method to be run on the added/updated object within the same lock scope which added/updated it. The only overloads available provide for custom factories to generate unique key values.

Comment: @Enigmativity I need to operate (in the example, call `Reset()`) on an item in the `ConcurrentDictionary`. If I obtain a reference to the item, I can only make the call to `Reset()` as a second call. In a multi-threaded run-time environment, some other thread could update or even remove the item AFTER retrieval but BEFORE the call to `Reset()`. The end result is that `Reset()` might fail to execute as expected because it is operating on an object which was either:
a) replaced (and I only have a reference to the old one), or
b) changed in a way which now makes the call inappropriate.

Comment: @Mellevsen - That's not the problem you're solving, that's the code you're writing to solve the problem. What's your business problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`ConcurrentDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2) is thread-safe in the sense that it protects its internal state from corruption. It does not protect from corruption the state of the objects it contains as keys or values. After retrieving an object from the `ConcurrentDictionary` using the [`GetOrAdd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.getoradd) method, if you want to mutate the state of this object and the object is not thread-safe, you are responsible for synchronizing the access to this object from multiple threads by using locks or other means. In other words, the thread-safety guaranties offered by the `ConcurrentDictionary` class are limited to itself.

You may still want to use this class, even if it does not cover all your thread-safety needs, because its granular internal locking implementation can be quite efficient in cases of high thread contention.

Comment: Thanks @theodor-zoulias - you've confirmed my suspicion that there is no way to run code within the same lock scope. Therefore, replacing items in the collection is never going to work 100%, so we'll need to handle thread safety within the item class (eg. MyWorker) itself.

Comment: Yeap I have noticed (from questions here in SO) that the `ConcurrentDictionary` class often creates greater expectations than what it can actually deliver. :-)